# TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating '$("#typed").typed')

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a plugin Typed.js
When I initialize the function the error mentioned pops up.
It suggests that the jquery is not loaded before the plugin but I don't see why.

HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="typed.js"></script>
```

in the header.

And

```
<script>
function type(){

$("#type").typed({
    strings: ["^1000to the biggest student organised fest in Kanpur", "to the biggest student organised fest in UP", "to the biggest student organised fest in <span style='color: #ffee00'>India</span> ^800."],
            typeSpeed: 10,
            stringstops: [41, 41, 41],
            backDelay: 600,
            showCursor: true,
            loop: false,
            contentType: 'html', // or text
            // defaults to false for infinite loop
            loopCount: false,
});
}

window.onload=type;
</script>
```

at the end of the body.

Can anybody find the mistake please?

Comment: The code here doesn't correspond with the error message. `$("#type").typed()` vs. `$("#typed").typed()`

Comment: Yes but that was on purpose. I modified the error message because #type is my id whereas #typed was used in the plug-in example and most people would search for that as question.

Answer (score 1):

Check your code , having duplicate `<script src="js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>` is equal to **not including jQuery**.

remove the duplicate  ...

Answer (score 0):

If jQuery wasn't loaded, then it would throw a reference error on `$`.

It says `.typed` is undefined so either:

1. Your URL to `src="typed.js"` is not returning the script *or*
2. The script doesn't give jQuery objects a `typed` property

Assuming I've found the right script, it definitely isn't option 2: http://jsfiddle.net/1gap1b39/

Check the Net tab of your developer tools to make sure you are getting a `200 OK` response for the script.

Comment: should OP have to use `$(function(){ .... })` DOM ready before implement `$("#type").typed`?

Comment: @jogesh_pi — No. It's called `onload` which is after DOM ready.